# Soft AP for TP Link WN727N

Tags: wireless-access-point

I could use utility for tp link products to use my wifi adapter to work as a router with soft ap. But I can't find any utility for my product. So, I really need guidance.

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I was on windows before and now I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `iw list` terminal command.